# Business-Logic Relationships in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

Can anyone please tell me how can one estabilish `1 to 0..1` and `1 to 1..*` relationships between tables in SQL (Server)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1 to 1..***

Create a Foreign key from a parent table to the primary key of the child (lookup table).

```
CREATE TABLE  A
(
   id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Somecolumn int,
   SomeOtherColumn Varchar(50),
   B_id int CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES B(id),
   -- ...other columns
)

CREATE TABLE  B
(
   id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Name Varchar(50)
)
```

**1 to 0..1**

Create a table with the primary key also defined as a Foreign key to the parent table

```
CREATE TABLE  [Master]
(
   id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   Somecolumn int,
   SomeOtherColumn Varchar(50),
   -- ...other columns
)

CREATE TABLE [Child]
(
   id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   OtherColumn Varchar(50),
)

ALTER TABLE Child
   ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Master FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Master(id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What about the parent tables?! Do they stay the same?!

Comment: @Mitch: In the Master-Child example, doesn't the `IDENTITY` in both the `Master` and `Child` cause any problems?

Comment: Making an IDENTITY column a foreign key makes very little sense and is probably unusable. @Mitch, I don't believe that was what you intended to show.

Comment: @Mitch I am not sure of 1 to Many because in both the table we are use the primary key and both are Identity Seed

Comment: @Mitch, there are at least 2 problems. The FK_Master constraint has a syntax error: you need to specify the referencing column. If the column you intended to specify was Id then you should remove the IDENTITY property from that column. It would be useless because you need to insert the value first to Master and then the same value to Child - so the IDENTITY is redundant.

Comment: @dportas: you are right on both accounts. updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One to many

1. Define two tables (example A and B), with their own primary key
2. Define a column in Table A as having a Foreign key relationship based on the primary key of Table B

This means that Table A can have one or more records relating to a single record in Table B.

If you already have the tables in place, use the ALTER TABLE statement to create the foreign key constraint:

ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_b ( b_id ) references b(id)

```
* fk_b: Name of the foreign key constraint, must be unique to the database
* b_id: Name of column in Table A you are creating the foreign key relationship on
* b: Name of table, in this case b
* id: Name of column in Table B
```